# Sequential request processing talend

Tags: talend

When sending requests to the talent in a certain sequence, with a small delay between requests, in the talent these requests are processed in a random sequence, I see this from the data recorded in the database, how can this be fixed

I was looking for a solution in CXF worqueue, but I don't understand how to set it up and if this is what I need

Sorry for my english

Comment: Can you provide the code? I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to explain. So I would appreciate if you could either provide a [mre] or (if MRE does not apply to this question) add some other aid to help us understand what you actually need help with. (Although for all I know this might make sense to someone who understands this software)

Comment: I have a web service running in talend osgi container (apache karaf). It processes the http request and writes the data to the database. When I in a loop asynchronously send several requests to this service, I expect that the data from these requests will be written to the database in the sequence in which I sent them, but this is not the case. I want to understand if I can somehow manage the processing of requests?
I think that now requests enter the queue and are processed by several threads, so the data is written to the database in the wrong order in which the requests came

Comment: If I haven't explained clearly enough, I'll make an example later

Comment: Hello, what components are you using to create the service ? (SOAP/REST , Data Intergration Components or Camel-based components (ESB) ?)

Comment: i am using REST components
tRESTRequest, tRESTResponse

Comment: Can you [edit] this information into the question?

Comment: Careful with REST services : there are multiple things that can make your job NOT thread safe, causing problems with mixed request/responses. Don't use : tHashInput/tHashOutput , tParallelize and tRunJob components, and don't update a context variable in your job service. (use global variables for that purpose). Those are limitations imposed by talend to make sure you have a thread-safe REST service.

Comment: @Corentin could you provide a reference for the not thread safe tHashInput/Output, please ? I use them often so I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: https://community.talend.com/s/article/Using-tHash-components-in-ESB-Runtime-MM5A4. Confirmed by Talend Consultants during a quickstart done on a recent project.

Comment: Thanks ! I think I'm safe with what I do with it, then.